# 1980-1900s Teen Boy Yellow bird animated creature comments on boy

Tags: story-identification, movie

Teen Boy talks to the audience every once in awhile like most old movies or shows. It could have been a Christmas movie as I remember a rendition of carol of the bells in the start it even that he was in a Christmas play maybe not. Throughout the movie a yellow bird like thing similar to what woodstock looked like on Charlie brown but with big white eyes would comment about his actions as a comedic add on. I am terribly sorry I can't be as descriptive as I'd like. This was a movie I watched as a little kid and it's so vague as I didn't watch it again over the years.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is there anything fantasy about this _other_ than a talking bird?  We don't generally consider animated talking animals to be on-topic unless there are other SF/fantasy elements.  (So Daffy Duck is off-topic, but Duck Dodgers is on-topic.)

Comment: I just realized this is solely sci Fi fantasy... I have no where else to go and really need help finding this movie